# Checar se botão está desabilitado - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho esse botão, e preciso verificar com JavaScript se ele está desabilitado, mas não sei como fazer isso. Eis o HTML:

```
<button type="button" title="Finalizar Compra" class="btn btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout no-checkout" disabled="disabled">
    <span>Finalizar Compra</span>
</button>
```

Estão vendo o `disabled="disabled"`? Então, como verifico isso?

O que já fiz foi:

```
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout no-checkout");

if(b == ???) { //Aqui que não sei o que fazer ???
    alert("Pedido minimo de: R$: 1250,00");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nota que o método [`getElementsByClassName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) devolve uma coleção, então para pegar somente o botão, tu pode pegar o primeiro item da coleção ou utilizar uma alternativa como [`getElementById`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp), já com o elemento, para verificar se ele está desabilitado ou não, basta checar o atributo (**disabled**):

```js
var b = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout no-checkout")[0];

if (b.disabled) { //Aqui que não sei o que fazer ???
  alert("Pedido minimo de: R$: 1250,00");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" title="Finalizar Compra" class="btn btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout no-checkout" disabled="disabled">
<span><span>Finalizar Compra</span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Pode me explicar uma coisa por gentileza? Eu programo em PHP, mas em JavaScript eu sou iniciante, não sei quase nada mesmo. Mas enfim, o . (ponto) do JavaScript é a mesma coisa que a -> (setinha) do PHP?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho eu não sou a pessoa certa para responder sobre PHP, mas até onde sei, são equivalentes sim.

Comment: Ok, obrigado, mas pode explicar so mais uma coisa? Por exemplo, você disse coleção. No caso, ele verefica quantos itens tem aquela class na página e depois organiza de 0 a vamos supor 10 por exemplo. Tem 10 botoes com a classe teste, ele vai organizar de 0 a 10 na página e vai meio que formar um array?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Exatamente isso, retorna uma coleção de todos os elementos com a classe especificada, organizando eles pelo index, começando em 0, p/ saber quantos elementos retornou, a coleção tem a propriedade `.length`.

Comment: Obrigado, Mathias! Ótimo dia pra ti! Abs;

Answer (score 3):

Se precisa buscar **um** elemento específico (seja por tag, classe, id, *data attributes*, etc) utilize [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). Faz mais sentido do que fazer o uso desse `getElementsByClassName`.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-proceed-checkout');

if(button.disabled)
  console.log('Está desabilitado.');
```

```html
<button type="button" title="Finalizar Compra" class="btn btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout no-checkout" disabled="disabled">
    <span>Finalizar Compra</span>
</button>
```

Poderia pegá-lo de outras formas também, por exemplo:

```
// Pelo título.
var button = document.querySelector('button[title="Finalizar Compra"]');

// Pelo atributo 'disabled'.
var button = document.querySelector('button[disabled]');

// Tendo atributo disabled e título específico.
var button = document.querySelector('button[disabled][title="Finalizar Compra"');

// Tendo todas as classes do seu botão.
var button = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-proceed-checkout.btn-checkout.no-checkout');
```

Se precisar obter uma coleção de elementos, utilize [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).